# Can't use multiple tags in cucumber Runner file in java

Tags: java, maven, junit, cucumber, appium

Can't use multiple tags in my cucumber with Appium Runner file, error is shown like below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rafPH.png),
using below dependencies in my pom.xml

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
```

I am trying to execute two feature file with tags @test and @test2

```
@test
Feature: Edit table TCT

  @appium
  Scenario: Edit table and add tmsurl ,appcode
```

```
@test2
Feature: TMS login scenarios

  @web
  Scenario Outline: Login with valid user name
```

Comment: Did you read the Javadoc on the `tags` attribute?

Answer (score 2):

I think your syntax is just not right, try the following:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {....},
        features= "...",
        glue= {"stepdef"},
        tags= "@test or @test2"
        )
public class TestRunner {
}
```

Comment: yes, it was success with this syntax